# result shows System.String[]

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, arrays

On my GetBusiness.aspx page i have create a test list

```
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        l.Add("one");
        l.Add("two");
        l.Add("three");
        l.Add("four");
        l.Add("five");

        // B.
        string[] s = l.ToArray();

        Response.Write(s);
```

No on my second page(default aspx page) I have some jQuery to load this array and show the results:

```
          $.get('GetBusiness.aspx', function (returndata) {
                            // for each address in returndata
                            alert(returndata);
```

but the result is : System.String[]
If I iterate , he iterate the string "System.String[]"

```
          $.each(returndata, function (index, value) {
              alert(index + ': ' + value); 
          };
```

How can I show the results from the string array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `Response.Write(s)` to :

```
JavaScriptSerializer objSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Response.Write(objSerializer.Serialize(s));
```

*Reference:* [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In your GetBusiness page, you are outputting the `.ToString()` property of the array, which is "System.String[]". You need to iterate the list and output each element separatly in some usable format, like JSON and then parse appropriately.

Example (untested):

```
string reponse = "";
response += "{ \"Output\":[";
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
  response += s[i];
  if (i < s.Length - 1) response += ", "
}
response += "] }";
Response.Write(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("one");
l.Add("two");
l.Add("three");
l.Add("four");
l.Add("five");

// B.
string[] s = l.ToArray();

Response.Write(string.Join(",", s));
```

javascript:

```
$.get('GetBusiness.aspx', function(returndata) {

    var arr = returndata.split(',');
    $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        alert(index + ': ' + value);
    });
});
```