# Returning datas from datatable in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable

DTName is a `DataTable` which returns rows in the code below...when I iterate it through the loop from 0 to its count. Only the data in first row is displayed.

How to get all the rows of the datatable displayed  in the result ?

```
DTName = GetClientNames()

   If Not DTName Is Nothing Then

      For i = 0 to DTName.Rows.count

         strName = DTName.Rows(i).Item("Client Name").Tostring()

      Next i

   End if
```

Comment: It seems this would be more appropriate with a For Each loop.

Comment: What is "the result"? What does `strName` do?

Comment: In this way on every loop you overwrite the strName value...

Comment: @styxxy :strName displays only the first row from the column name "clientName" from the datatable.

Comment: Then your problem resides in exactly what @mdn says?

Comment: how do you want to store all names in a single variable? comma separated? "john,luke,mike,..." or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`For i = 0 to DTName.Rows.count` would eventually throw a `IndexOutOfRangeException` error when the value of `i` equals to `DTName.Rows.count`, the limit should be `DTName.Rows.count - 1` .

To get all the values from all datarows, store them in a `List` :

```
    Dim strName As New List(Of String)

    For i = 0 to DTName.Rows.count - 1

       strName.Add(DTName.Rows(i)("Client Name").Tostring())

    Next i
```

Alternatively you could use `Foreach` like this :

```
    For Each DR As DataRow In DTName.Rows

       strName.Add(DR("Client Name").Tostring())

    Next
```

I also suggest you remove the redundant check if `DTName.Rows.Count > 0`

**EDIT :** You could Declare `strName` as `string` and append row values to it :

```
    For i = 0 to DTName.Rows.count - 1

        strName &= (DTName.Rows(i)("Client Name").Tostring() & ",")

    Next i

    Response.Write(strName)
```

Comment: I have tried both,it returns only the last row from the data table

Comment: @balaji I updated my answer to use a list, this way all the strings would be added to the strName List.

Comment: This is the result being displayed (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: what control are you using to display the result?

Comment: reponse.write in vb.net to display the result

Comment: @balaji Please edit your question and provide us with the details of the desired output. And also you should add a little bit more code to add some context.

Comment: @balaji Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077345/result-shows-system-string) question.

Comment: @styxxy..Please find my reformatted code above...There are totally 6 records in my database..but i can get only one row returned..I need to display all 6 records...

Comment: @Abzy: pls find my full code above for ur ref..let me knw...if u need anything else

Comment: @abZy..Sorry ..Serializer should not be used ..tats the criteria..is thr any other method to do

Comment: @abZy:Is there any way to display the Values of data seperately without using string...<html><body><a href="http://www.google.com"><%=strName%></a></body></html>..Coz,When i click the link it goes to google...all i need is each values has seperate client id's which has to appear in the URL am linking to..any possibilities..

Comment: @balaji I suggest you ask a new question regarding this issue, SO is saying **"Please avoid extended discussions in comments"**

Answer (score 0):

Double to check the actual `ColumnName` of the Column.

```
For Each item As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
    strName = item("Client Name").ToString()
    Console.WriteLine(strName)
Next
```

Comment: it seems that your problem is data for `DataTable` try to check your DataTable.